# Why can't I exclude the folder "META-INF" when compiling the apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, gradle-plugin

```
packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes.add("META-INF/**")
}
```

Some documents still exist.

I had to manually delete the META-INF folder and re-sign the apk. it worked fine.